# Getting following error in python: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100. Went through other solutions but I found it hard to understand

Tags: python, index-error

**My agent's objective is to control the speed of the motor. Here all state values are the rpm value of the motor and actions are defined as 0(decrease rpm by 1),1(no change) and 2(increase rpm by 1). I am using Q learning.**

```
class SpeedControlEnv(Env): #we can access gym env 
    def __init__(self): #initializing actions, observation, spaces,
        #Actions that we can take up, down, no change in speed
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        
        # Observation space to hold the current speed so our agent can take necessary action
        #self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0]), high=np.array([100])) #box is used for continuous state space
        self.observation_space = Discrete(100) #discrete observation space
    


        #set start temp
        self.state = 40 + random.randint(-30,40) #this is the start state for my agent.
        # set time for our agent to complete the task before my motor blows
        self.control_length = 60 # this is in seconds : So my agent has 'n' seconds to bring it in normal state 
        
        
    def step(self, action): #what actions agent can take in each steps
        #Take action (0,1,2)
        # 0 -1 = -1 #decreaase speed by 1
        #1 -1 = 0 #no change
        #2- 1 = 1 #increase speed by 1
        self.state += action -1
        #with each action reduce the time my agent has by 1
        self.control_length -= 1
        
        # assign reward
        if self.state >= 40 and self.state <= 45:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1
        # check if shower is done    
        if self.control_length <= 0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        #apply random noise
        #self.state += random.randint(-3,3)
        
        #set placeholder for information, Required by OpenAI
        info = {}
        
        #return step information
        return self.state, reward, done , info
            
        pass
    def render(self): #visualization 
        pass 
    
    def reset(self): #reset after training or a episode
        #Reset speed that is the state
        self.state = 40 + random.randint(-30,40)
        #Reset control time
        self.control_length = 60
        return self.state
```

#Defined my hyperparameters as
#Initialize all the hyperparameters

```
num_episodes = 50000 #agent plays step
#max_steps_per_episode = 60 #max steps agent can take in one episode

learning_rate = 0.1 #alpha
discount_rate = 0.99 #gamma

exploration_rate = 1 #epsilon
max_exploration_rate = 1 #max epsilon
min_exploration_rate = 0.01 #min epsilon
exploration_decay_rate = 0.01 #decaying rate of exploration
```

#My Q learning code is as follow

```
for episode in range(num_episodes):
  state = env.reset()
  done = False
  reward_current_episode = 0
  
  for step in range(env.control_length):
    exploration_rate_threshold = random.uniform(0,1)
    if exploration_rate_threshold > exploration_rate:
      action = np.argmax(q_table[state,:])
    else:
      action = env.action_space.sample()

    new_state,reward,done,info = env.step(action)

    #Update Q table
    q_table[state,action] = q_table[state, action]*(1-learning_rate) + learning_rate*(reward + discount_rate*np.max(q_table[new_state,:]))

    state = new_state
    reward_current_episode += reward

    if done == True:
      break
  exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate)*np.exp(-exploration_decay_rate*episode)

  #append rewards from current episode to the list of rewards achieved from all episode

  reward_from_all_episodes.append(reward_current_episode)
  each_state.append(state)
```

#error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6020/777037272.py in <module>
     14 
     15     #Update Q table
---> 16     q_table[state,action] = q_table[state, action]*(1-learning_rate) + learning_rate*(reward + discount_rate*np.max(q_table[new_state,:]))
     17 
     18     state = new_state

IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100
```

**It will be great if anyone can explain to me why I am getting this error. I am new to programming and machine learning.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to index a numpy array. Arrays, and just about everything in python and programming in general, are 0-indexed. That means their indices start at 0 instead of 1, which means that the maximum index in an array with 100 items is 99.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it does not help me. here my observation space is 100 discrete values from (1 - 100). I understand that python indices start with 0. Here q_table is off size 100*3. Can you explain to me what specifically I am doing wrong to get this error?

Comment: @romeshprasad you should double check and print your index values : state and action. The error states that you try access to index 100 which does not exists as your column/axis is from 0 to 99.

Comment: @Malo I figured out that under the function reset if I change it to any other value than the one used to start the state, the code executes and does not give any error. But yet I don't know the reason for it. I will try to figure it out. Thank you for your help guys.